# What is the role of UserDetailsService in AuthenticationManager from Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to create a login page which returns a JWT if the login is successful but I can't understand how some functionalities work. I'm currently following a nice tutorial for JWT authentication where the author creates a "/login" endpoint which looks like :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody LoginUserDto loginUser) {
    try{
      authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(//email,//password));
    }catch(BadCredentialsException exception) {....}

    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(//email);
    return createToken(userDetails.getUsername());     
}
```

Why is he still calling `userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()` if the `authenticate()` method doesn't throw any `BadCredentialsException` ?

Anyway, I've seen that this `userDetailsService` is configured inside a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}
```

But again, what is the purpose of this `UserDetailsService` if he uses the `AuthenticationManager` ? Because I've seen in almost every tutorial that I need to implement this interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UserDetailsService` is used to load the user from a back-end structure like database. The `loadUserByUsername` method is called when a user tries to login with a username and password. The method `loadUserByUsername` returns an `UserDetails` object where you can get the user’s authentication and authorization information (more specific information from you domain user, like: employee number, full name) . So, you may need it for a more detailed usage during application flow, like getting to know if the user full name adhere to a logic. Calling `authenticationManager.authenticate` you get to check the credentials against the provider (LDAP, Database, OAUTH and etc).

Creating a custom `UserDetailsService` object is an easy mechanism that allows for **Spring Security** to make security decisions based on your custom domain model. **Spring Security** requires `UserDetailsService` in order to use the built-in remember-me support and `UserDetailsService` object does not work when authentication is not based on a username and password.